# Correlation of multivariate distributions without "slope"

Tags: correlation, covariance, multivariate-normal-distribution

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation) has this image showing different correlations:

[image]

It says:

> The correlation reflects the noisiness and direction of a linear relationship (top row), but not the slope of that relationship (middle) … the figure in the center has a slope of 0 but in that case the correlation coefficient is undefined because the variance of Y is zero.

But if the variance of Y is *not* zero, but still different from that of X, such as in this image:

[image]

Does it still have the same value of correlation that it would have if rotated?  It seems not, since the covariance goes to zero and [that's the numerator of the correlation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation#Definition)?  (Since there are just as many positive $\operatorname{E}[X⋅Y]$ terms as there are negative.)

I'm confused about [this paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2110786) which talks about the "correlation" of multivariate normal distributions, and says things like this:

> To facilitate the large number of simulations involved, in each case
> rotation to principal axes was employed to diagonalize the correlation
> matrix (Morrison, 1976, ch. 8). This permits Monte Carlo generation of
> independent normal variates with variances equal to the eigenvalues of
> the correlation matrix.
> …
> (The correlation for this scatter plot is .5; the distribution has been
> rotated to principal axes.)
> …
> The correlation matrices used to produce this table assume that all off-diagonal
> correlations are the same (either all 0 or all .5).

Would it be possible to measure the correlation of such a distribution?

Similarly, [this paper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/american-political-science-review/article/abs/toward-applicable-social-choice-theory-a-comparison-of-social-choice-functions-under-spatial-model-assumptions/8CA954293702CFD0D5FDD0DA9EA12792) generates distributions like this:

> All
> voters are represented by their ideal points in a
> four-dimensional space, that is, by a four-tuple
> of real numbers. The four numbers are generated in the following way: voter i's position
> on the first dimension, Y1i, is chosen from a
> standard Gaussian (normal) distribution (mean
> zero, standard deviation 1.0). The voter's position on the second dimension Y2i, is generated
> from the first dimension position by perturbing
> it with Gaussian noise of mean zero and
> standard deviation 1.4. The third position is
> produced from the second with fresh noise of
> similar character, and the fourth is generated
> from the third in the same fashion.

But wouldn't this process create distributions shaped like above, with no slope and therefore no measurable correlation?  Yet they show a correlation matrix where all the values are between 0 and 1:

[image]

They also say

> The values
> on all dimensions are then normalized to have
> unit variance.

Which I would think would make the distribution completely symmetrical in every dimension and no longer even have this type of no-slope "correlation".

I'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

The correlation coefficient is not invariant under rotations. You can always rotate your random variables to make them uncorrelated. The middle row of plots from Wikipedia is indeed a bit misleading in that regard, because it suggests that the correlation coefficient does not change under rotation. But this only happens when the distribution is degenerate - If you would produce the same plot with a non-degenerate distribution, you will see that the correlation coefficient gradually reduces to zero.

The converse of the above is that you can take a vector of independent (and therefore uncorrelated) random variables and rotate them such that the rotated variables are correlated - this is the procedure the quote from the first paper refers to.

As for the second paper, note that the second variable $y_2$ "*is generated from the first dimension position by perturbing it with Gaussian noise*", namely

$$y_2 = y_1 + \varepsilon_2$$

which means that $E[y_2|y_1] = y_1$, so the joint distribution lies around the line $y_2=y_1$ or has a "slope" of $45^\circ$.

Comment: OK, the caption says it, too "The correlation reflects the … direction of a linear relationship … but not the slope of that relationship".  So "rotation to principal axes" *creates* the correlation from a distribution like the uncorrelated one I've shown?  I misinterpreted and thought it was the other way around. Googling "principal axis" doesn't seem to talk about distributions at all.

Comment: "y2=y1+ε2" Oh, so it's [y1, y1+ε2, y1+ε2+ε3, ...] not [y1, ε2, ε3, …]